# I am trying to Access the private Poloniex trading API in Unity C# but am getting the error "invalid command"

Tags: c#, private-key, trading, poloniex

I am trying to Access the private Poloniex trading API in Unity C# but        am getting the error "invalid command" I have my API Key and Secret authorized on Poloniex for the Trading API but can't seem to get access with my current code:

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;


    public class PolonScript : MonoBehaviour {


        public TextMesh OutputText;

        const string _apiKey = "---Key---";
        const string _apiSecret = "---secret---";


        void Start () {

            string nonce = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");

            string myParam = "command=returnBalances&nonce=" + nonce;


            const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://poloniex.com/tradingApi";
            try
            {
            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
                if (webRequest != null)
                {
                    webRequest.Method = "POST";
                    webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    webRequest.Headers.Add("Key", _apiKey);
                    webRequest.Headers.Add("Sign", genHMAC(myParam));
                    webRequest.Headers.Add("command", "returnBalances");
                    webRequest.Headers.Add("nonce", nonce.ToString());


    using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                        {
                            var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            OutputText.text = jsonResponse.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OutputText.text = ex.ToString();
            }




        } //end-of-start()
```

Here is my current signing method which I am quite sure has a mistake (Human error) within, am I doing something wrong obliviously here?

```
        private string genHMAC(string message)
        {
            byte [] APISecret_Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_apiSecret);
            byte [] MESSAGE_Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            var hmac = new HMACSHA512(APISecret_Bytes);
            var hashmessage = hmac.ComputeHash(MESSAGE_Bytes);

            var sign = BitConverter.ToString(hashmessage).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            return sign;
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poloniex Command should not be sent in the header, you should send it as a POST parameter, that's why it's responding "invalid command". Take a look at this answer to see how you send POST parameters in c#:[How to add parameters into a WebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279888/how-to-add-parameters-into-a-webrequest)

Here's an example of how your Start method should look like:

```
void Start()
{

    string nonce = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");

    string myParam = "command=returnBalances&nonce=" + nonce;


    const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://poloniex.com/tradingApi";
    try
    {
        var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Key", _apiKey);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Sign", genHMAC(myParam));

            byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"command=returnBalances&nonce={nonce.ToString()}");
            webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;

            Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                {
                    var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    OutputText.text = jsonResponse.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OutputText.text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave a look and removed it from the header, in fact I am able to remove everything from the header except for the KEY and Secret and I still get "invalid command."

Is this normal? It also doesn't seem to matter if I use my key/secret combination vs. random letters so I know there's something additional wrong even before the HMAC section

Comment: here is the inside of the Web Request:

//webRequest.Method = "POST";
    //webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
    //webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.Headers.Add ("Key", _apiKey);
    webRequest.Headers.Add ("Sign", genHMAC (myParam));
    //webRequest.Headers.Add ("command", "returnBalances");
    //webRequest.Headers.Add ("nonce", nonce.ToString ());

Comment: You need to send the command, you can't just comment it out, i think the response you're getting is normal. Try sending the command as I specified in the answer and see if it still returns the same error. If you have any trouble writing the code just let me know and i will try to help.

Comment: Are you talking about this part in what you showed me?:     if (request.Method == "POST")
                    {
                        if (postData != null)
                        {
                            request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
                            using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                            {
                                dataStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect how the code would look like, could you give it a try and see if it solves the "invalid command" issue?

Comment: Wow! I am glad to see something other than "invalid command."

Now I get this which is better: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Comment: My API Key and Secret are correct, does this mean I have an error in my HMAC?

Comment: I think your genHMAC function should just be "private string genHMAC()
{
 byte [] APISecret_Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_apiSecret);
 var hmac = new HMACSHA512(APISecret_Bytes);
 return hmac;
}"

Comment: I am still getting error(403) however if I take out the "HHmmss" from the nonce I get error(422), I know the command is indeed the correct command because if I misspell it (purposely to troubleshoot test) it returns the old invalid command so either its my HMAC set up how you did or it's my nonce that is forbidding me

Comment: I think it should be your nonce, i would try creating a new one and testing again. Also, could you accept the answer? I think the original question about the "Invalid command" has been solved, i will still keep helping you.

Comment: I accepted your answer; What do you mean by creating a new nonce? isn't it new every millisecond?

Comment: Sorry, i mixed things up, i meant you should try creating a new API key.

Comment: I did, still forbidden, if I dissect and don't add the key header at all it says    {"error":"Invalid API key\/secret pair."}  same if I comment out the Sign header,  but when I put anything in right key or wrong key it says (403)forbidden

Comment: Check this github issue: https://github.com/dutu/poloniex-api-node/issues/20, it can help you. Can you also send the body of the 403 response?

Comment: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Comment: No, we need the 403 response body, not the exception stack trace. See this answer for how to get it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409138/c-sharp-getting-the-response-body-from-a-403-error

Comment: I started it as a new question, is this the response body at the very bottom section here?:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833192/poloniex-c-sharp-trading-api-webrequest-comes-back-403-forbidden
           If you're able to answer the new one too take a shot