# Poloniex C# Trading API webRequest comes back (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, webrequest, sha512, poloniex

I have my code down to the essentials for testing access, but am receiving the good old error(403) from the server, I have verified for double-sure I am using the correct API Key/Secret pair. My Code (C# via Unity 3D) is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

public class PolonScript : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public TextMesh OutputText;    

    const string _apiKey = "---apiKey---";
    const string _apiSecret = "---apiSecret---";

    void Start()
    {   
        string nonce = DateTime.Now.ToString ("HHmmss");      

        const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://poloniex.com/tradingApi";
        try 
        {
            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create (WEBSERVICE_URL);
            if (webRequest != null) 
            {
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                //webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";    

                byte[] dataStream = 
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("command=returnBalances&nonce=" + nonce);    

                webRequest.Headers.Add("Key", _apiKey);
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Sign", genHMAC (dataStream));   

                Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
                newStream.Close();    

                using (System.IO.Stream s = 
                        webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) 
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s)) 
                    {
                        var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        OutputText.text = jsonResponse.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (WebException ex) 
        {
            OutputText.text = ex.ToString();
        }           
    }
    //end-of-start()

    private string genHMAC(byte[] dataStreamInput)
    {    
        byte [] APISecret_Bytes = 
               System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_apiSecret);
        HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(APISecret_Bytes);    

        var signBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(dataStreamInput);    

        string HexDecString = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < signBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            HexDecString += signBytes[i].ToString("X2");
        }

        return HexDecString;    
    }
}
```

So why am I receiving the (403) Forbidden using accurate credentials?

I tried this to see the reason:

```
catch (WebException ex) 
{           
    OutputText.text = ex.Response.Headers.ToString ();
}
```

and receive the following

```
//Date: Sat, 14 Apr 2018 15:34:56 GMT
//Content-Type: application/json
//Transfer-Encoding: chunked
//Connection: keep-alive
//Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dd1b32592915674669120afbf8181141b1523720096; expires=Sun, 14-Apr-19 15:34:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.poloniex.com; HttpOnly
//Cache-Control: private
//Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-//uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
//Server: cloudflare
//CF-RAY: 40b73d4b8c98552e-ORD
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that is because your `Sign` header is not valid.

---

You can doublecheck if your sign function is ok using those fake `nonce` and fake `secret`, and verify that the `sign` is good

- post data: `nonce=123456&command=returnBalances`
- nonce: `123456`
- secret: `123456`
- `sign` will be: `b56174398987d15deee73885ca178ba82c414c7f27e763a9aa3cfc41c5b1373980ed83638bbf8c66dc62c20cbf35e770ad264af8571d22bc7c96fae9740dac0`

If the sign is different please share your `genHMAC` code function.

---

You may try this version to generate the `sign` header:

```
private readonly string _apiKey = "123456"; 
private readonly string _apiSecret = "123456"; 
private long nonce = DateTime.Now.Ticks;




private string CreateSignature()
{
    //string msg = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _apiKey);

    return ByteArrayToString(SignHMACSHA512(_apiSecret, StringToByteArray(_apiKey))).ToUpper();
}

private static byte[] SignHMACSHA512(String key, byte[] data)
{
    HMACSHA512 hashMaker = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
    return hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
}

private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
}

private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] hash)  //rimuove - e converte in bite
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

Then:

```
   const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://poloniex.com/tradingApi";
    try
    {


        var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Key", _apiKey);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Sign", CreateSignature());     // keysecret 

            var postData = "&nonce=&command=returnBalances";
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);




            using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                {
                    var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Response: {0}", jsonResponse));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Source: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1590683.0

Comment: I get F21E6ECC2EE587A4DF217EEDFA38F87CC72.... etc.  my genHMAC is: 



private string genHMAC(byte[] dataStreamInput)
    {    
        byte [] APISecret_Bytes = 
               System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_apiSecret);
        HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(APISecret_Bytes);    

        var signBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(dataStreamInput);    

        string HexDecString = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < signBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            HexDecString += signBytes[i].ToString("X2");
        }

        return HexDecString;    
    }

Comment: I update answer to add a C# CreateSignature() func & post request example